# Can we merge doctrine querybuilders and retrieve each ones' results ? is that a best practice?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a website where I populate the first page with objects of different nature (last posts, last recipes, last ingredients published). I have currently one querybuilder and then one query for each of them because I call ->getQuery()->getResult() on each of them.

Is there not a way to merge all those querybuilders before executing the query so as to retrieve an array of results made of the results of each of those querybuilders ?

Would that be a best practice ? How would we do it ?

EDIT: what I hoped we could do:

```
$recipesQueryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository('Recipe')->createQueryBuilder('r');
$postsQueryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository('Post')->createQueryBuilder('p');

$results = mergeQueryBuilder($recipesQueryBuilder, $postQueryBuilder)->getQuery()->getResult();

$recipes = $results['r'];
$posts = $results['p'];
```

Comment: Nope.  SQL queries can only return one record format at a time.  So unless your posts, recipes, ingredients share exactly the same schema then individual queries will be required.

Comment: too bad! thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I do this with many of our queries.  I doubt there is a formal "best practice" for this kind of thing, however I can vouch for the fact that re-using builders does simplify the code.  For example:

```
public function getListBuilder(User $user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('l')->where('l.user = :user')->setParameter('user', $user)->orderBy('l.name');
}
```

I have a number of queries that re-use this base builder.  For example:

```
public function countLists(User $user = null)
{
    $qb = $this->getListBuilder($user);
    return $qb->select('COUNT(l)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Likewise another method `findActiveLists()` changes the order to `createdAt` and generates a query with `setMaxResults()` specified.

Comment: thanks but sorry, this is not really my question. I'll add an example.